# Send / Receive Emails through external VServer with Plesk?

Tags: imap, plesk, cname, mail-server, virtual-server

I have:

- Google Cloud Engine (Google does not allow to Send Mails)
- Domain (GoDaddy)
- External VServer with Plesk.

I want to user my VServer as an external Mailserver. 
But i don´t know what to write in the "CName (Alias)" and "MX (Mail Exchanger)".

And where do i have to point my imap.server.tld and smtp.server.tld in my Emailclient?
to imap.plesk-vserver.tld or to imap.my-regualar.tld

What´s about the origin of my emails i send out?
Do i need to configure Plesk as well?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here how to Receive emails on Plesk server:

Assume that your "Domain (GoDaddy)" = domain.tld

In "Domain (GoDaddy)":

- create new DNS record for MX
- create new A record to point MX on plesk server IP

[image: Plesk MX DNS record]
[image: Plesk A DNS record]

Where 1.2.3.4 - it's IP of your plesk server

In Plesk create new subscription or new add-on domain with name "domain.tld"

Point your email client for IMAP on IP address of Plesk server.

To *Send* emails from "Google Cloud Engine" I recommend to use some external service like SendGrid / MailChimp or change your application to send mail via SMTP on Plesk server.